# iPhone app on Xcode 4: Error while submitting app to Apple store: At least one valid architecture arm6 must be present

Tags: iphone, xcode4, app-store

Could anyone please tell me why I am getting this error message while sending application to apple store. I have made sure that Application target settings have valid architectures armv6 and armv7!

ARCHS = $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)
SDKROOT = iphoneos
ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = YES
SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS = iphoneos
VALID_ARCHS = armv6 armv7

Thanks.

Comment: Do you get any error/warning when building the distribution build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that your `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH` is set to `YES`, which means that product includes only code for the native architecture as set in `NATIVE_ARCH` ("Valid Architectures" setting).

Please try changing "Build Active Architecture Only" to `NO` in "Build Settings" of your target. This way `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH` is `NO`, so XCode can build all the valid architectures which are specified in `ARCHS` ("Valid Architectures" setting).

For more details about build settings, check out Apple's doc [Xcode Build Setting Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html).

If you're not using preview/beta version of Xcode, this should do the trick. Note: I never tried to make a distribution build on beta version and I have no idea how it can result in the error you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use XCode 4.2 preview version ?

You can't use beta and pre-GM version (for ios) to submit app in itunes connect